# discord.py :-My Bot is jut not responding and either no error is there in compiler

Tags: python, discord.py

I just started learning discord.py but my bot isn't responding even though I followed the documentation and no error messages. The bot is online but doesn't respond to my messages
I was attempting to do this from a tutorial

```
import os
import discord


client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
 .format(client)) 

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Please Someone Help me! :(

Answer (score 0):

Your bot can't read the content of the messages sent in a guild because it is missing the [message_content intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.message_content).

You gave your bot only the [default intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.default), which doesn't include the message_content one.

> client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

Here is how you fix it:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

In case your bot isn't still able to read the content of the guild messages, you need also to turn on the message content intent in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications):

1. Select your app, in my case it would be *"test"*:

[image: Step 1]

2. Select the `Bot` tab in the left panel:

[image: Step 2]

3. Scroll untill you see the `Privileged Gateway Intents` section. Turn the `message content intent` on:

[image: Step 3]

Now your bot should be able to read the content of the messages sent in guilds.

[Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#intents) you can read more about Intents

Comment: Thank You Brother for giving your precious time but that code didn't work and message content intent is already on :(

Comment: I tried the code myself and it is working [(screenshot)](https://i.imgur.com/QzQgaUa.png). Make sure you are not writting $Hello (uppercase H). If that is not the case, could you try to add in your code a print() like [this](https://i.imgur.com/MyDN7CP.png)? Check if you can see in your terminal the content of the messages you are sending in discord

Comment: Please can you send me the full code of bot I can't figure it out and please tell me which module or package you install and use

Comment: in my compiler @client.event :- @ is in different color client is in different color and event is in different color, I just sign-up today so I don't know how to attach screenshot file :c

Comment: [Screenshot of the code](https://i.imgur.com/NbDRAlV.png). You just need to install discord: ```pip install discord```

Comment: Check these 3 things as well. 1.- When executing your code, make sure that your bot goes online successfully (bot appears online in discord and you see the "We have logged in as ..." in the terminal where you are executing the code). 2.- Try using the $hello command in direct message with your bot (your bot doesn't need any extra permission / intent in dms). 3.- Check if your bot has the right permissions on your server / guild (at least see the channel where you are sending the $help command in + send messages)

Comment: Thank You Brother I was busy in some other work.
Now I tried again it worked perfectly