# Why ctx commands run only in bot dm? not working in group server

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
   await ctx.send("hi")
```

This code is running only in direct message with bot.
I don't know why it is not running in my server.
Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Your bot is probably missing the [message_content intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.message_content), which is needed in order to have access to the content of messages in guilds (servers). [In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74045886/20214407) I explain how to enable it.

In case your bot still can't get access to the messages content, make sure that your bot has permissions in the server to:

1. Send messages
2. At least read the channel in where you are using the command

Comment: Thank you for you advice. But there can be error with python version? I am now 3.7 version.

Comment: Did you check the intents, as recommended by Jabro?

Comment: [Python 3.7 isn't enough for using new features introduced in discord v2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#python-version-change) so if your version of discord.py is v2.x, you should consider upgrading your python version. However, in the code you showed, there isn't anything that doesn't work when using python 3.7 version. You need to enable the message content intent. As you can see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20intents#discord.Intents.message_content), your bot won't be able to read the content of messages otherwise